# Android, jfeinstein sliding activity with a Google Map in it sliding when user touches map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, slidingmenu, jfeinstein

In my android app I have a [jfeinstein sliding menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) , I enabled the sliding gesture to show and hide it.

In one of my activities I have a google map, but when I touch the map to navigate into it, if i slide my finger from left to right, the menu appears and the map doesn't move.

Is there a way to prevent the menu from sliding in and 'pass' the touch event to the map in order to let the user navigate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to resolve your issue:

1. The easy way - sliding menu way, is to use the methods within the library and disable the sliding menu on certain activities/fragments. This is achieved by using the [setTouchModeAbove](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/library/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/SlidingMenu.java)

   ```
    // Allows the SlidingMenu to be opened with a swipe gesture on the screen's margin
    mSlidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);

    // Denies the SlidingMenu to be opened with a swipe gesture
    mSlidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);

    // Allows the SlidingMenu to be opened with a swipe gesture anywhere on the screen
    mSlidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
   ```
2. The most general solution would be to use [onTouchIntercept](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) method to decide is a touchevent should be passed through another view or it should be consumed by that viewgroup. The internet has enough examples addressing this.

Comment: mSlidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN); solved my problem..thank you!